# NOTICE: using pg_pltemplate information instead of CREATE LANGUAGE parameters

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am getting this error message (shown in title), when I run this SQL statement in PG 8.4:

```
psql -h localhost -U postgres -d mydb -c "CREATE TRUSTED PROCEDURAL LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' HANDLER plpgsql_call_handler VALIDATOR plpgsql_validator"
```

What's causing this (it used to work with earlier versions of PG), and how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [procedure has been simplified](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createlanguage.html). For `plpgsql` simply use:

```
CREATE LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The error message tells you, that `plpgsql` is among a number of predefined languages listed in the system table `pg_pltemplate`. Just have a look:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_pltemplate;
```

In PostgreSQL 9.0 and later, PL/pgSQL is pre-installed by default.