# Upgrading from Postgres 7.4 to 9.4.1

Tags: postgresql, psql, pg-dump

I'm upgrading Postgres from ancient 7.4 to 9.4.1 and seeing some errors.

On the old machine, I did:

```
pg_dumpall | gzip > db_pg_bu.gz
```

On the new machine, I did:

```
 gunzip -c db_pg_bu.gz | psql
```

While restoring I got a number of errors which I don't understand, and don't know the importance of. I'm not a DBA, just a lowly developer, so if someone could help me understand what I need to do to get this migration done I would appreciate it.

Here are the errors:

```
 ERROR:  cannot delete from view "pg_shadow"
 DETAIL:  Views that do not select from a single table or view are not automatically updatable.
 HINT:  To enable deleting from the view, provide an INSTEAD OF DELETE trigger or an unconditional ON DELETE DO INSTEAD rule.
```

I also got about 15 of these:

```
 NOTICE:  SYSID can no longer be specified
```

And this, although this looks harmless since I saw plpgsql is installed by default stating in version 9.2:

```
 ERROR:  could not access file "/usr/lib/postgresql/lib/plpgsql.so": No such file or directory
 SET
 NOTICE:  using pg_pltemplate information instead of CREATE LANGUAGE parameters
 ERROR:  language "plpgsql" already exists
```

A big concern is that, as it restores the databases, for each ne I see something like this:

```
 COMMENT
 You are now connected to database "landrush" as user "postgres".
 SET
 ERROR:  could not access file "/usr/lib/postgresql/lib/plpgsql.so": No such file or directory
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure most of them can be fixed by using Google. [plpgsql problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8680870/notice-using-pg-pltemplate-information-instead-of-create-language-parameters), [WITH SYSID](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/016201c60649$c6254b70$0264a8c0@demolish1) has been removed and might require code changes to get it up and running. Depending on your experience with PostgreSQL, it might be worth contacting your local DBA or asking separate and as specific as possible questions (ie. providing MVCEs and such).

Comment: @tambre my code does not use SYSID. This error message occurs before psql connects to any database. So it seems that some kind of system thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically two ways. Both are difficult for the inexperienced. (and maybe even for the experienced)

- do a stepwise migration, using a few intermediate versions (which will probably have to be compiled from source). Between versions you'd have to do a pg_dump --> pg_restore (or just the `psql < dumpfile`, like in the question). A possible path first hop could be 7.4 -> 8.3, but maybe an additional hop might be needed.
- Edit the (uncompressed) dumpfile: remove (or comment out)  anything that the new version does not like. This will be an iterative process, and it assumes your dump fits into your editor. (and that you know what you are doing). You might need to redump, separating schema and data (options --schema-only and --data-only, I don't even know if these were available in PG-7.4)

BTW: it is advisable to use the pg_dump from the newer version(the one that you will import to). You'll need to specify the source host via the -h flag. The new (target) version knows about what the new version needs, and will try to adapt (upto a certain point, you still need to use more than one step) I will also refuse to work if it cannot produce a usable dump. (In which case you'll have to make smaller steps...)

Extra:

- if the result of your *failed* conversion is complete enough, and if you are only interested in the basic data, you could just stop here, and maybe polish a bit.
- `NOTICE:  using pg_pltemplate information instead of CREATE LANGUAGE parameters` I don't know what this is. Maybe the way that additional languages, such as plpgsql, were added to the core dbms.
- `ERROR:  language "plpgsql" already exists` : You can probably ignore this error. -->> comment out the offending lines.
- `DETAIL:  Views that do not select from a single table or view are not automatically updatable.` This implies that the postgres RULE rewrite system is used in the old DB. It will need serious work to get it working again.

Comment: Might be worth adding to this the tip from the pg_dump man page to use the pg_dump tool matching the target/new version to create the backup.

Comment: Yep, I'll ad that. Thanks!

Comment: @wildplasser thanks very much! Well that all sure looks like a major pain. I did a new pg_dumpall with the clean option (have not tried doing it with the newer pg_dumpall yet) and when I fed it into psql it seemed to work. Copied the data in and build indexes. I may do it again just making users and such, then a separate dump for the data. That might make editing the file easier. Is there a way to see if what I imported into the new version is good? The data seems to be there...

Comment: The simple way is: do the counting. If you know your data, and your dumpfile fits into the editor, and you don't have too many tables, this will work.